# Sikuli keeps getting an error

Tags: robotframework, sikuli

Sorry im a total noob with this. So ive tried integrating Sikuli in my Working RF setup meaning, I have to move from Python to Jython for this to work. my problem now is that im always getting an error.

```
Error in file 'C:\robot\suites\Test\Test.robot': 
Importing test library 'Selenium2Library' failed: ImportError: No module named decorator
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\Selenium2Library\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from keywords import *
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\Selenium2Library\keywords\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from _logging import _LoggingKeywords
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\Selenium2Library\keywords\_logging.py", line 4, in <module>
    from keywordgroup import KeywordGroup
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\Selenium2Library\keywords\keywordgroup.py", line 4, in <module>
    from decorator import decorator
  File "C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages\Selenium2Library\keywords\keywordgroup.py", line 4, in <module>
    from decorator import decorator
PYTHONPATH:
  C:\jython2.7.0\bin\jythonsikuli.bat
  C:\jython2.7.0\Lib
  __classpath__
  __pyclasspath__/
  C:\jython2.7.0\Lib\site-packages
CLASSPATH:
  C:\jython2.7.0\jython.jar
  C:\Sikuli\sikulix.jar 
20180308 11:23:08.246   ERROR   Error in file 'C:\robot\suites\Test\Test.robot': 
Getting keyword names from library 'Remote' failed: Calling dynamic method
'get_keyword_names' failed: Connecting remote server at http://localhost:8270 failed:
[Errno 10061] Connection refused
```

Answer (score 0):

In your error message there are two issues clearly defined:

> Importing test library 'Selenium2Library' failed: ImportError: **No module named decorator**

Which can be solved by installing the relevant Python Module from PIP:

```
pip install decorator
```

The second issue is towards the end:

> Connecting remote server at http://localhost:8270 failed:
>   [Errno 10061] **Connection refused**

This means that Robot Framework is unable to make a connection on port `8720`. This is often due to:

- Firewalls preventing an opened port to be accessible. In Windows add a FireWall rule allowing for port 8270 to be accessible from the outside.
- Try and connect using `http://127.0.0.1:8270`. Although often a synonym for localhost at a technical level it is not the same.